# Multi level objects in Angular JS return null on deeper levels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I've got this weird issue, but it's probably just me not knowing what I'm doing.

I've got this object with the following structure:

```
userData.user
  data: 
    email: ""
    name: ""
    etc.
```

image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ZCi.png

Worth mentioning that userData is a factory. I store my data retrieved through a service globally there.

when I access userData.user, I get all the details visible in my dev console. However, when I try to access userData.user.data, all the values are "null" and I, yet when I go back a level, I still see all the data.

What am I doing wrong? Have I just over complicated the whole structure?

```
 app.factory('sessionAuth', function($http){        
    var uData = null;        
    function load(path, $email, $password, $passwordConfirm, $uName) {           
        return $http({
                    url: path,
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {email: $email, password: $password, passwordc: $passwordConfirm, username: $uName, rM: null}
                });            
    }

    if(uData != null) {        
        return uData;

    } else {            
        uData = {    
            getUserData : function($email, $password) {
                return load('system/login.php', $email, $password);
            },
            getSession : function() {
                return load('system/LoggedinCheck.php');
            },
            registerUser : function($uName, $email, $password, $passwordConfirm) {
                return load('system/register.php', $email, $password, $passwordConfirm, $uName);
            }
        };

        return uData;        
    }
});
```

this I use as a global variable.

```
app.factory('userData', function(){        
    var u = {};        
    return {
        user: u
    };        
});
```

that's the controller which gets the data.

```
 controllers.controller('lrFormCtrl', function($scope, sessionAuth, userData, $location){        
    $scope.userData = userData.user;

    $scope.login = function(u){
        sessionAuth.getUserData($scope.email, $scope.password).then(function(data){
            $scope.userData.data = data.data;
            if($scope.userData.data.name.length > 0) {
                //$location.path('/main');
            }
        });
    };
});
```

And this is the directive that uses userData

```
 app.directive('transitionLogin', function(userData, $location) {        
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {            
        console.log(userData.user.data);

        function checkToggle(){                
            var cList = element[0].classList;                
            for(i = 0; i < cList.length; i++) {

                if(cList[i] == 'ng-login-toggled') {
                    return true;
                }                    
            }
            return false;                
        };

        var signIn = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('signIn-toggle')[0]);

        signIn.on('click', function(){
            console.log(checkToggle());
            console.log(scope.userData);
            if(checkToggle()) {
                scope.login();
                console.log(userData.user.data);
                if(userData.user.data.name.length > 0) {
                    TweenMax.to(element, 0.3, {y: 100, opacity: 0, ease: Quad.easeOut}).delay(0.2);
                    $timeout(function(){$location.path('/main')}, 550, true);
                }
            }                
        });            
    }        
});
```

However, worth noting. When I do a check whether user has setting to "Remember" his login checked, the data is retrieved and I can navigate through the userData object without any errors.

It seems to only be a problem when I try to access that in a directive

Comment: show us the factory, and how you're accessing the factory in your directive

Comment: Need code to understand what/how you're doing things.

Comment: Will post in a second.

Comment: Actually, I do believe this is happening because the data is not yet retrieved. I need to wait until the data is fully retrieved.